# opendir and readdir returns utf8

Tags: php, directory, filesystems

Why does this return utf8 chars on one server but not on another? Some filenames contain unicode chars like `æ` `ø` and `å`..

In some environments utf8 chars are printed and in some iso chars are printed

```
header('content-type: text/plain');
$handle = opendir("./dir");
while($readdir = readdir($handle)){
    echo "$readdir\n";
}
```

output `Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8`

```
Retursvar 2 med fejl p� debiteringsniveau.xml
Retursvar 2 med fejl på debiteringsniveau.xml
```

The same locales are installed on both systems (UTF8)

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Comment: What underlying filesystem is in use? Is it the same filesystem in use on servers that return different results?

Comment: All systems are Debian Jessie - same distros

Comment: Ok, next question - how are you setting the Content-Type. I'm assuming you're running via a webserver and viewing in a browser? Is the content type set via 'header()' or inline html??

Comment: its in a `header()`.. the pages are viewed as plain text

Comment: You're looping over the directory incorrectly, instead of it being `while($readdir = readdir($handle)){
    echo "$readdir\n";
}` it should be: 
    `while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        echo "$entry\n";
    }` as stated in the readdir() function documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php). This won't fix your current problem, it might prevent one from happening later in your project.

Answer (score 2):

You may find that you web server is running under a different locale on each system.

To determine this run the following php via your webserver:

```
<?php
system("locale");
```

Chances are the webserver returning the correct characters is running in either a 'utf8' locale or 'C'.

The locale that the webserver uses can be set in different places. Either by using the system wide locale - or a service specific one. You probably need to investigate the reason for any difference and decide whether to update your system wide locale or just the webserver.

On Debian, the system wide locale change be changed using

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

And following the prompts.

Alternatively, for service specific locales. Set the 'LANG' environment variable to the one you require in the service init script prior to starting the service. There's probably a service specific config file you could also search out to persist the change in event of webserver upgrades.

Comment: The exact same locales are installed on both systems.. Both UTF8

Comment: To clarify - the system locale can be different to the one that the webserver, or any other process is running under. What method did you use to determine that both webservers are running as UTF-8?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a PHP question, it's a system question. The problem probably stems from misconfigured locales on one of the systems. If you run `locale` you can inspect which locales are currently installed. If the locale is not marked as UTF-8 this will be your problem. Installing the correct UTF-8 locale will fix the issue.

Comment: The exact same locales are installed on both systems.. Both UTF8

Answer (score -1):

Try to set utf-8 encoding in your header:

```
header('content-type: text/plain; charset:utf-8');
```